# Why doesn't Perl's $OSNAME work on Solaris?

Tags: perl, variables, operating-system, perl-module

I remember having used the variable `$OSNAME` in Linux.

Currently I'm working on a project on Solaris where I need to get the OS name and that variable is not working on Solaris.

Even a simple one line program does not work:

```
print "OS is $OSNAME\n";
```

it prints

```
OS is
```

Please help.

Comment: Always `use strict` and `use warnings` in your scripts.

Comment: see http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-do-I-find-out-which-operating-system-I'm-running-under%3f

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use the `English` module.

`$OSNAME` is actually an alias for `$^O`, you can use `$^O` without using `English` module but to use `$OSNAME` you need to use the `English` module.

Also since `use strict` is missing you did not get any errors.

**Always** use `use strict;` in your program, it will help you catch these kinds of errors.

So try:

```
use English;
use strict;

print "Operating system is $OSNAME\n";
```

Comment: Always use English qw(-no_match_vars); or it slows you program down

Answer (score 2):

You can use `print $^O`instead.

Answer (score 2):

Testing stuff from the command line, I get:

```
$ perl -E 'say $OSNAME'

$ perl -Mstrict -E 'say $OSNAME'
Global symbol "$OSNAME" requires explicit package name at -e line 1.
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
$ perl -Mstrict -MEnglish -E 'say $OSNAME'
linux
```

Answer (score 2):

If `$OSNAME` (`$^O`) doesn't contain precisely the information you need, take a look at the values available to you from the [Config](http://perldoc.perl.org/Config.html) module.